# Raspberry pi project question control a machine

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I have a project that I work on that need to block a machine automatically  (an industrial oven ) in a specific time based on a maintenance  planning , I was wondering if it's possible to work with raspberry pi and a relay card to block it since it consumes a lot of voltage 380V ??Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, just get a relay card which supports 380V

Comment: I don't know how you want to implement this, but if this is timing critical, the [`GPIO` module](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) says, that a raspberry may not be a good solution

Comment: Thanks jeril .user8408080 what do you suggest?